# numpy's linalg norm axis does not output the same result

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to maximize computation performance using numpy (remove python for loop). Here is my initial implementation

```
np.random.seed(128)
l = []
for i in range(1000): 
    v = np.random.randn(7)
    l.append(np.linalg.norm(v))

l = np.array(l)
l
```

The above code simply takes the Frobenius norm of a vector of size 7, and appends it to a list. This is repeated for 1000 times. To remove the for loop, I construct a matrix of size (1000, 7), and then take the norm of the matrix with axis=1 as shown below.

```
np.random.seed(128)
v = np.random.randn(1000, 7)
v = np.linalg.norm(v, axis=1)
```

However, when I check for equality of `l` to `v` with `np.all(l == v)`, it outputs `False` for me. I don't understand why numpy behaves in such way. I checked the dtype of values for `v` and `l` and both are `np.float64`

Comment: Use `np.allclose`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read the following [issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5697).

it is said there:

> numpy in general does not guarantee that semantically equivalent
>   operations like this will produce identical results. Even operations
>   like sum can produce different results depending on memory layout (and
>   this is on purpose -- making them identical all the time would require
>   either big slowdowns or intentionally reducing precision).

so this is where the difference lies, you should not expect the same results but the same results up to tolerance. so the simplest solution to compare them will be the one suggested by **Divakar**:

```
np.allclose(l,v)
```

another possible option is:

```
np.array_equal(np.round(l,12),np.round(v,12))
```

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question